# React material-table/core Localization for selected Rows not working

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, material-table

I have a table as below and I am on `@material-table/core: 0.2.52` version

```
<MaterialTable
      isLoading={loading}
      title=""
      columns={[
        {title: 'Track', field: 'track'},
        {title: 'Tier', field: 'tier'},
        {title: 'Architecture', field: 'architecture'},
        {title: 'Archtier', field: 'archtier'},
        {title: 'Lifecycle State', field: 'lifeCycleState'},
      ]}
      data={data}
      options={{
        selection: true,
        rowStyle: {
          fontSize: '14px'
        }
      }}
      localization={{
        toolbar: {
          nRowsSelected: '{0} application(s) selected'
        },
        body: {
          emptyDataSourceMessage: `No applications found with owner email ${selectedEmail}`
        }
      }}
      onSelectionChange={(rows) => onSelect(rows)}
    />
```

When I select all or individual row checkbox, I should see something like this below (Screenshot from using (https://github.com/mbrn/material-table)
[image: Screen Shot 2022-11-08 at 8 17 34 AM]

But I am seeing nothing
[image: Screen Shot 2022-11-08 at 8 18 17 AM]

am I missing any options here?

My dependencies in package.json

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.10.4",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.10.4",
    "@material-table/core": "^0.2.52",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.10.6",
    "@mui/lab": "^5.0.0-alpha.100",
    "@mui/material": "^5.10.6",
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "filefy": "^0.1.11",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-google-charts": "^4.0.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.4.0",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.1",
    "sass": "^1.54.9"
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

This has been reported and got fixed in v0.2.53
https://github.com/material-table-core/core/issues/660